# about detecting iris and pupil circles using hough circle in java opencv

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio, image-segmentation, iris-recognition

I'm using opencv in Java to try to detect circles (iris, and pupil) in images with eyes, but I didn't get the expected results.

Here is my code

```
// convert source image to gray
org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imgCny, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
//fliter

org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.blur(imgCny, imgCny, new Size(3, 3));
//apply canny

org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny(imgCny, imgCny, 10, 30);
//apply Hough circle

Mat circles = new Mat();
Point pt;

org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.HoughCircles(imgCny, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, imgCny.rows() / 4, 2, 200, 100, 0, 0);
//draw the found circles
for (int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++) {
    double vCircle[] = circles.get(0, i);

    pt = new Point((int) Math.round((vCircle[0])), (int) Math.round((vCircle[1])));

    int radius = (int) Math.round(vCircle[2]);
    Core.circle(mRgba, pt, radius, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
}
```

[`the original image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Z2V.jpg)

[`canny result`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1G91.jpg)

I don't know what is the problem. Whether the problem is in the parameters of the found circle function or something else.

Has anyone faced such problem or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please, share the intermediate result (Canny) and the original image. And I think that the blur step is not necessary because you want to have sharp edges.

Comment: @FiReTiTi , I edited my question above and add the original image and the canny result. actually I delete the hough circle result because I have limitation here for adding links or photos (no more than two links)

Comment: I had the same problem with hough circle for locating pupil, it turned out that hough circle is not proper for this case because pupil is not exact circle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that the Hough transform will detect THE circle you want in this canny result! There are too many edges. You must clean the image first.

Start with black (the pupil, iris inner part) and white detection. These two zones will delimitate the ROI.

Moreover, I would also try to perform a skin detection (simple threshold into HSV color space. It will eliminate 90% of the research area.